# NiFi - Convert comma delimited string in json to array

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I'm looking for a way to convert a comma delimited string in a json to an array in NiFi.

Then length of the array is variable. I've tried a few things now, including using the jolt transformer, but the version of jolt with nifi doesn't support split.

My flow file looks like:

```
{
  "arrStr": "abc,def,hij",
  "something": "else"
}
```

And I'm trying to convert it to:

```
{
  "arrStr": ["abc", "def", "hij"],
  "something": "else"
}
```

**Update 7/10:**

Sorry, should have included that I am on nifi version 1.7.1 which I think has jolt version 0.1.0.

Comment: you can use script - groovy, python, ...

Comment: @daggett - yea that's true. I'll probably give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

This works

"split" unit test case
https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/7812399d1c955742d81eae363244a2d0ef86cf3b/jolt-core/src/test/resources/json/modifier/functions/stringsSplitTest.json

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "arrStr": "=split(',',@(1,arrStr))"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: So the jolt that comes with the nifi I'm using is version 0.1.0, which doesn't seem to support the split operation.

Answer (score 0):

Shout out to @daggett for commenting about groovy. I went with that route and it's real easy to do. I had to use ExecuteScript processor, not the ExecuteGroovy processor, as the ExecuteGroovy processor didn't load up the IOUtils I wanted to use.

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

def flowFile = session.get();
if (flowFile == null) {
    return;
}

flowFile = session.write(flowFile,
        { inputStream, outputStream ->
            def content = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

            def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(content)
            def builder = new JsonBuilder(slurped)
            
            builder.content.arrStr = builder.content.arrStr.split(',')
            
            outputStream.write(builder.toPrettyString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
        } as StreamCallback)
        
session.transfer(flowFile, ExecuteScript.REL_SUCCESS)
```